# Backup iCloud notes?

Tags: notes.app

I have 7000 important notes on Mac notes. I once moved them to iCloud to back them up.

Recently, I tried to log out of iCloud briefly to fix a bug, and it almost deleted all my notes.

I really need a way to get them backed up on either a hard copy, or on my mac's hard drive. How can I do this?

Comment: Common misconception: iCloud is *not* a backup service, rather a syncing service between devices. Have a look at TimeMachine, its builtin and easy to use.

Comment: If its a syncing service, why do I need to buy more space?

Comment: Well, because the files are stored on an Apple Server, then distributed to your devices. Its a *you change/delete the file on some device and the change will be **synced** across your devices* service. A backup includes the **history** of your documents. I.e. TimeMachine (depending on storage capacity) keeps an hourly, daily and weekly history. So you can get back a file from two weeks ago and 10 weeks, but also 4 hours ago.

Comment: what system are you running and what is your computer?

Comment: Mojave, on a late 2016 Macbook Pro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an app called Exporter that will export each note in Notes to a markdown or html file to any folder you choose. So you could save these to an external drive or another internal drive. Its not blazing fast. i just saved 700 files in about 1.5 minutes. So figure 15 minutes to save 7000 files. Exporter is free from App Store. Go to Exporter/Preferences to change output files from Markdown to HTML if thats the format you want.